# Serialization Error using Corda Docker Image

Tags: docker, corda

I get the following error (for each node), when I run the command docker-compose up. I configured the network parameters myself as well as the nodes, not using the network bootstrapper.

```
[ERROR] 08:07:48+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: Serialization scheme ([6D696E696D756D], P2
P) not supported. [errorCode=1e6peth, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/1e6peth]
```

I have tried to change the properties in the network-parameters file, yet unsuccessfully so far.

Here are my config files:

```
myLegalName : "O=Notary, L=London, C=GB"
p2pAddress : "localhost:10008"
devMode : true
notary : {
    validating : false
}
rpcSettings = {
    address : "notary:10003"
    adminAddress : "notary:10004"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        user="user"
        password="test"
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
    }
]
detectPublicIp : false
```

```
myLegalName : "O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB"
p2pAddress : "localhost:10005"
devMode : true
rpcSettings = {
    address : "partya:10003"
    adminAddress : "partya:10004"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        user=corda
        password=corda_initial_password
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
    }
]
detectPublicIp : false
```

```
myLegalName : "O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB"
p2pAddress : "localhost:10006"
devMode : true
rpcSettings = {
    address : "partyb:10003"
    adminAddress : "partyb:10004"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        user=corda
        password=corda_initial_password
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
    }
]
detectPublicIp : false
```

as well as my network-parameters file and my docker-compose.yml file:

```
minimumPlatformVersion=4
notaries=[NotaryInfo(identity=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, validating=false)]
maxMessageSize=10485760
maxTransactionSize=524288000
whitelistedContractImplementations {

}
eventHorizon="30 days"
epoch=1
```

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  Notary:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-4.0:latest
    container_name: Notary
    networks:
      - corda
    volumes:
      - ./nodes/notary_node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./nodes/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters

  PartyA:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-4.0:latest
    container_name: PartyA
    networks:
      - corda
    volumes:
      - ./nodes/partya_node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./nodes/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/libs/:/opt/corda/cordapps

  PartyB:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-4.0:latest
    container_name: PartyB
    networks:
      - corda
    volumes:
      - ./nodes/partyb_node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./nodes/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/libs/:/opt/corda/cordapps

networks:
  corda:
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like the bytes reaching the serializer are corrupted: every message starts with a "magic" header identifying the serialization version, and this error is what you get if the header doesn't match any known serialisation scheme.
The reported bytes spell "minimum" in ASCII -- perhaps something is trying to send your docker-compose.yml to the port that handles incoming RPC messages?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! You are right, it didn't match the serialisation scheme. After all I dediced to use the network bootstrapper, because it didn't make sense to implement the serialisation myself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is indeed the issue with missing serialization scheme.

Also, in our most Corda 4.4 release, we have released an official image of the containerized Corda node.

Feel free to check out our most recent guide on how to start a docker format node. https://medium.com/corda/containerising-corda-with-corda-docker-image-and-docker-compose-af32d3e8746c